# Changing names of many folders with Windows console or batch file

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, console

I have a folder with many folders inside. They have a name pattern: dd-mm_PSD and I want them to be named with that pattern: mm_dd_PSD becouse it's easier to manage. Can I do it "globally" with console or some batch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
cd <your-top-folder-here>
for /f "tokens=1,2,3* delims=-_" %d in ('dir /s/b *PSD') do ren "%d-%e_%f" "%e_%~nd_%f"
```